# hyperledger fabric mychannel block in peer get deleted once the container is down

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have hyper-ledger fabric setup with 2 organisation which works well.I am keeping the separate storage for the blocks state in file system. Now i turn down the all organisation container, all the states inside the container is deleted, but i am keeping  states which are stored the my file path. Next, when i use the existing file storage, and turn up the docker, all the peers and ordered load well from the state which i was stop. The problem here is, I am unable to reinitiate the channel transaction and i am unable to join the same channel from the peer. where does the mychannel.block get stored. when i try to join the channel i get error

> 2019-11-27 03:49:01.631 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialised
>   Error: genesis block file not found open mychannel.block: no such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know what volumes are you using to persist that file.

You should persist:

- `/var/hyperledger/production` in your orderers and peers.
- `/opt/couchdb/data` in your CouchDB containers.
- Wherever you store your MSP, TLS files and other configuration files (genesis block, etc.). Only you know about your configuration.
- `/var/lib/postgresql/data` in your CA's PostgreSQL container.
- Whatever other file/folder you want to persist.

Anyway, I don't know if I have understood you, but if you persist all these, you don't need to join a channel **again**, the peers remain joined after restarting the network.

Comment: thanks for replay, i tried it, now i understood, if i have storage of previous data peer, when i stop and run again the docker container of peers. i don' t have to rejoin to channel bcoz previous data keep track of everything.